# Fixed element resize-able by inner elements

Tags: css, html, fixed

I've got this code in css:

```
div#show{
background-color:black;
position: fixed;
width:100px;
height:100px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;

margin: auto;
}
```

It centers a black box on my page. However I want to make it non-constant size.

```
div#show{
background-color:black;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;

margin: auto;
}
```

But in this situation it covers whole page. Is there solution to make it as big as needed to cover inner elements?

Answer (score 0):

using `position: fixed;` makes the element ignore its parents and fit to window.

You could just `left: 20%; right: 20%; top: 20%; bottom: 20%;` or similar and it would stretch to fill screen leaving 20% around the outside…

If you set the parent with `position:relative` and then

```
div#show{
  background-color:black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  margin: auto;
}
```

it would only stretch to cover the parent element

Comment: I'm talking about streching to children elements.

Comment: @oneat The size of the parent will be dictated by the children, so your `#show` div will stretch to the size of the children combined.

Comment: But it doesn't. It covers from edge to edge.

Comment: What do you want to cover? Each child element individually? or all the child elements with one block?

Comment: I've got image in this fixed (position fixed) element And I want it to be centered.